# Chrome on Intel Atom x86 image on AVD

Tags: android-emulator, intel-haxm

Is there any way I can install Chrome on my Lollipop x86 image. I tried installing it via ADB, but I get an INSTALL FAILED NO ABIS error. I was able to get ES File Explorer to load and I pushed chrome.apk to /sdcard. When I tried installing from ES, it gives me App Not Installed.
I also tried installing Amazon AppStore but got the same error so it is not related to Google APIs.

So is there any way I can get apps to work on my x86 Intel image?
ARM is really slow and choppy.

Comment: Get a x86 build of that app. Most apps are only compiled for ARM because of the native libraries they use. Play Store for instance takes care of determining which apps are compatible with your device.

Comment: Could you please point me to it (link to .apk file)? Also, is there any place where I can get x86 .apk files?

Comment: Well, you have to take a look inside the apps yourself. Some come bundled with both (`/lib/x86` exists together with some `arm*` folders) or without any at all (no `/lib` folder); those can be installed without further issues. If there is only a `/lib/arm*` folder, then you are out of luck and have to search for one that has a `/lib/x86` folder inside of it.

Comment: Also many free or open source apps have their x86 builds available on their websites (VLC for instance)